# Why is spacing after the "eduation" section different from the other sections?

Tags: spacing

The spacing after the "education" section is smaller than the spacing after the other sections. What is the difference? Also, how do I make them all alike?

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}



%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-2pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-2pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingt}[6]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
      \textit{\small#5}\\
      \small #6\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\releventCourseWork}[6]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.30\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \item{#1} & \item{#2} & \item{#3} \\
       \item{#4} & \item{#5} & \item{#6} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[1]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\LARGE \scshape XXX XXX} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small XXX $|$ \href{mailto:x@x.com}{{xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com}} $|$ 
    \href{https://github.com/...}{{github.com/xxxxx}}
\end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheadingt
      {XXX }{XXX}
      {XXX}{Expected: December 2023}
      {XXX}
      {XXX}
    \resumeSubheading
      {XXX}{XXX}
      {XXX}{Expected: December 2023}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------RELEVANT COURSEWORK------------
\section{Relevant Coursework}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \text{Object Oriented Programming}\hspace{1cm}
     \text{Analysis of Algorithms}\hspace{1cm}
     \text{Database Structures}\hspace{1cm}
     \text{Programming in C}\hspace{1cm}}}
 \end{itemize}

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {XXX}{XXX}
      {XXX}{XXX}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{XXX}
        \resumeItem{XXX}
        \resumeItem{XXX}
        \resumeItem{XXX}
      \resumeItemListEnd
    
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------PROJECTS-----------
\section{Projects}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
     
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{XXX} $|$ \emph{XXX}}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{XXX}
            \resumeItem{XXX}
            \resumeItem{XXX}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------PROGRAMMING SKILLS-----------
\section{Technical Skills}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: Python, Java, C\#, SQL(MS SQL Server), C, C++, JavaScript/HTML/CSS} \\
     \textbf{Frameworks}{: React, Django, .NET, Angular} \\
     \textbf{Developer Tools}{: Git, Docker, Kubernetes, Postman, Google Cloud Platform, Azure} \\
    }}
 \end{itemize}
 
%-----------LANGUAGES-----------
\section{Languages}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \text{English}\hspace{1cm}
     \text{Spanish}}}
 \end{itemize}
%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Looks like that is the only section that does not end with an itemization. Maybe they (the itemizations) are responsible for the extra space in the other sections? I also note that you do a lot of manual tweaking with sizes and so. It might be better to use macros to avoid them in the text.

Comment: don't do ` \small{\item{`   size changes like `\small`  do not take an argument, and `\item` should not be in a group and does not take an argument so both `{` should be removed. If you _must_ have a size change in the document (it would be better to be in your command definition) use `\small\item` with no `{`